# Is there a way to get the data range of a different spreadsheet in google app scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm currently trying to write a script inside a spreadsheet (SP1) which gets the data range/values of a different spreadsheet (SP2) and looks at the values of SP2 and fills the cells of SP1 as long as they match.

For example, spreadsheet 1 contains a cell called Salary, and spreadsheet 2 contains a cell called Salary with multiple values of salaries in the cells below. Ultimately when I run the code, it should lookup the similar cells (Salary) and copy the values from SP2 to SP1 below Salary in SP1.

What I'm not sure how to do is to access the data range/values of a different spreadsheet, while having the data range of an active spreadsheet.

I thought using `SpreadsheetApp.OpenById()` would help out, but I haven't found a way to make it work.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

```
function hireEIB() { 
  var dr1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getDataRange(); 
  var data = dr.getValues(); 
  var dr2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1l1F_xwG8HDQuQNYsU1OGvfniOlUvqTooVk‌​-oZllXivo").getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues(); 
}
```

Comment: You are on the right track.  SpreadsheetApp.openById() is the correct approach.  Please provide more details about the problem that you are having.

Comment: What I'm trying to do next is to assign the spreadsheet data range/values (which only contains one sheet) to a variable. This is where I'm running into errors. My next line is `var dr2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getDataRange().getValues();`

Answer (score 0):

The following code changes should help you to make additional progress.

```
function hireEIB() { 
  var id = "1l1F_xwG8HDQuQNYsU1OGvfniOlUvqTooVk‌​-oZllXivo";
  var inputRange = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  var inputValues = inputRange.getValues();

  //Set destination range to be the size of the input range
  var destRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,inputValues.length,inputValues[0].length);
  destRange.setValues(inputValues);
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, however, I'm not trying to set the ranges to be the same.  Spreadsheet 2 (or my input range) contains a lookup keyword (Salary) aswell as several inputs (ex. 1000, 555, 30, etc.). Spreadsheet 1 only contains the specific lookup keyword (Salary). What I'm trying to achieve once the code runs is to match the keywords, and then extract the data inputs from SP2 and add them to SP1 below the keyword. Sort of like an automated copy/paste. Does this make sense? I did modified my code by using part of your example. You can see the modification in the question.

Comment: I suggest that you revise the question (or create a new question) that contains some sample input data and your best attempt at coding a solution.  That will make it easier for folks to give you recommendations.